# Performance issue after upgrading to Java 7 update 25 on SunOS 5.10

Tags: java, performance, sunos

Recently we updated our Java 7 update 7 to update 25, on **SunOS 5.10 Generic_144488-17 sun4v sparc SUNW,Sun-Blade-T6340** machine. Right after the update we got serious performance issues from our application that deployed on WebLogic 11g.

During thread dumps analytic we discovered that the following code cause to thread dump that halts the application.
This code is executed every 30 seconds:

```
import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory;
import java.lang.management.ThreadInfo;
import java.lang.management.ThreadMXBean;

ThreadMXBean threadBean = ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean();
ThreadInfo[] allThreadsList = threadBean.getThreadInfo(threadBean.getAllThreadIds(), isObjectMonitorUsageSupported, isSynchronizerUsageSupported);
```

**Thread Dump:**

```
at sun.management.ThreadImpl.dumpThreads0(Native Method)
at sun.management.ThreadImpl.getThreadInfo(ThreadImpl.java:440)

at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor620.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:75)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor265.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:279)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.StandardMBeanIntrospector.invokeM2(StandardMBeanIntrospector.java:112)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.StandardMBeanIntrospector.invokeM2(StandardMBeanIntrospector.java:46)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MBeanIntrospector.invokeM(MBeanIntrospector.java:237)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.PerInterface.invoke(PerInterface.java:138)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.MBeanSupport.invoke(MBeanSupport.java:252)
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
at weblogic.management.jmx.mbeanserver.WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase$16.run(WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase.java:449)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at weblogic.management.jmx.mbeanserver.WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase.invoke(WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase.java:447)
at weblogic.management.mbeanservers.internal.JMXContextInterceptor.invoke(JMXContextInterceptor.java:263)
at weblogic.management.jmx.mbeanserver.WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase$16.run(WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase.java:449)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at weblogic.management.jmx.mbeanserver.WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase.invoke(WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase.java:447)
at weblogic.management.mbeanservers.internal.SecurityInterceptor.invoke(SecurityInterceptor.java:444)
at weblogic.management.jmx.mbeanserver.WLSMBeanServer.invoke(WLSMBeanServer.java:323)
at javax.management.MBeanServerInvocationHandler.invoke(MBeanServerInvocationHandler.java:292)
```

Anybody knows why this happens only after upgrade to update 25? I didn't find any comment about this change.

Thanks All.

Comment: Why are you doing that?  Wouldn't the obvious fix be to *stop* doing that?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what the cause of this is ... but one possible solution is to try using [`dumpAllThreads`](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/lang/management/ThreadMXBean.html#dumpAllThreads%28boolean,%20boolean%29) instead of what you are currently doing.

But it is also a but puzzling that your *production* code is doing that ... every 30 seconds.  Taking a thread dump involves taking a snapshot of every thread's stack frames.  That's liable to be expensive, especially if you have lots of live threads.  If you could say what you are trying to achieve, maybe we could suggest a light-weight alternative.

Comment: The snipped code above is deprecated code that will be deleted. I am trying to understand why this code effects my application only after upgrading to Java 7 update 25.

Comment: @MaximKirilov - Like I said, I can't answer that.  I couldn't find a Bug report that seems relevant.  However, there are resources available that you can use to figure it out for yourself.  1) Try the releases between u7 and u25 in turn to figure out when the behaviour changes.  2) Find / look at the list of all bugs changed in that release.  3) See if you can reproduce the problem on another platform.  4) Examine the OpenJDK Java 7 source code *history* to track down what changed ...